# Searching inside a subfolder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I search a file thats inside a subfolder

Here's my code it currently searches the parent folder only it won't search inside the sub folder:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ListBox1.Items.Clear();
       string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/files"));

       foreach (string item in files)
       {
           string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item);
           if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower()))
           {
               ListBox1.Items.Add(fileName);
           }

       }
}
```

Comment: Is this all subfolders or one particular one? is "files" the subdirectory or is it one inside of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           ListBox1.Items.Clear();
           string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/files"),  "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

           foreach (string item in files)
           {
               string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item);
               if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower()))
               {
                   ListBox1.Items.Add(fileName);
               }

           }
    }
```

Comment: I get redline when I put `SearchOption.AllDirectories`

Comment: @NatsuDragneel sorry forgot to put the pattern ! The edited file code should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ListBox1.Items.Clear();
       DirectoryInfo di =
           new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/files"));
       FileInfo[] files =
           di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
       foreach (FileInfo item in files)
       {
           string fileName = item.Name;
           if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower()))
           {
               ListBox1.Items.Add(fileName);
           }
       }
}
```